# Custom priority queue comparator that accesses private members of a class

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

If you look at the code below, I am trying to create a `priority_queue`, I have named it `DijkstraPriorityQueue`, that has a custom comparator which also uses the private vector `distTo`.

You can see that I have some dots `.......` as everything I tried have failed.

What is the cleanest solution (or possible solutions) to make this work as intended in this specific case ?

**Dijkstra.h**

```
class Dijkstra
{
public:
    Dijkstra(Graph G, int s);                          // Create
    ~Dijkstra();                                       // Destroy

private:
    bool compare(int u, int v)
    {
        return distTo[u] < distTo[v];
    }
    typedef priority_queue<int, vector<int>, .........> DijkstraPriorityQueue;


    vector<float>         distTo; // distTo[u] is the distance of the shortest s->u path 
    DijkstraPriorityQueue PQ;     // Min-Priority Queue, implemented for Dijkstra
};
```

**Dijkstra.cpp**

```
Dijkstra::Dijkstra(Graph G, int s)
{
     PQ = DijkstraPriorityQueue(...........);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option #1

```
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

class Dijkstra
{
public:
    Dijkstra()
        : PQ([this](int u, int v){ return distTo[u] < distTo[v]; })
    {
    }

private:    
    using DijkstraPriorityQueue
       = std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::function<bool(int,int)>>;

    std::vector<float> distTo;

    DijkstraPriorityQueue PQ;
};
```

#### Option #2

```
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

class Dijkstra
{
public:
    Dijkstra()
        : PQ(std::bind(&Dijkstra::compare, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2))
//      or
//      : PQ([this](int u, int v){ return compare(u, v); })
    {
    } 

private:    
    bool compare(int u, int v) const
    {
        return distTo[u] < distTo[v];
    }

    using DijkstraPriorityQueue
       = std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::function<bool(int,int)>>;

    std::vector<float> distTo;

    DijkstraPriorityQueue PQ;
};
```

#### Option #3

(For the record, if you are stuck with C++03):

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

class Dijkstra
{
public:
    Dijkstra()
        : PQ(compare(this))
    {
    }

private:
    struct compare
    {
        explicit compare(Dijkstra* d) : d(d) {}

        bool operator()(int u, int v) const
        {
            return d->distTo[u] < d->distTo[v];
        }

        const Dijkstra* d;
    };

    typedef std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, compare> DijkstraPriorityQueue;

    std::vector<float> distTo;

    DijkstraPriorityQueue PQ;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked and it seems exactly like what I needed. I am using Option #1 right now.

Comment: Is the way I am creating the PQ, creating the queue on the stack ? Should I be using a pointer instead ?